# “Data type mismatch in criteria expression” error in C# when I click on save button

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strcmd = "INSERT INTO student VALUES('" + txtsname.Text + "','" + txtsrollno.Text + "')";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strcmd, MyConn);
        if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { MyConn.Open(); }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { MyConn.Close(); }

        showData();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does student have more than 2 columns?

Comment: no thy have only 2 columns

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: when m click on save bttn they give me “Data type mismatch in criteria expression" message

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Roll No is of integer type and you are trying to insert string data by enclosing value in single quotes.

**Use Parameters.** They will save you from SQL Injection and will prevent errors like the above. You can do something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strcmd = "INSERT INTO student VALUES(@name,@rollno)";
        using (OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection("connectionstring"))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strcmd, MyConn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtsname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", int.Parse(txtslrollno.Text));

                if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { MyConn.Open(); }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { MyConn.Close(); }

                showData();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually using my code i m inserting three entires in that table,bt now i m trying to insert new entry they give me error...

Comment: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @user3308969, are you sure you are getting the exception in the same code ?

Comment: formate of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index0.

Comment: thanks all of you ,now my code work properly,actually my text box was mismatch, again thanks for giving your valuable time for me ..

Answer (score 0):

this error is due to may be your table columns for name and roll number have different type. In code you are passing text so in database these columns should have varchar data type.

Comment: i am check my table name are text type & rollnumber are number

Comment: i am using ms access for storing data

Comment: then you need to convert your roll number to integer like this . string strcmd = "INSERT INTO student VALUES('" + txtsname.Text + "','" +Converter.ToInt(txtsrollno.Text) + "')";

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Converter<TInput,TOutput>' requires '2' type arguments,now this error come..

Comment: sorry user Convert.ToInt32()

Comment: what value you are entering in your text box for roll number??

Comment: integer like this.123

Comment: i'm reporting my answer below please check it.

Comment: thanks all of you,now my code work properly,actually my text box was mismatch, again thanks for giving your valuable time for me ..

Comment: you are wellcome please mark the appropriate answer which helped you in fixing your program it will help others facing same problem. thanks

Comment: can you tell me how to make two login in same form,in my project two type login first one admin & second is staff.when user login it first select its user type e.g admin or staff i am using combo box for selecting user type..

Answer (score 0):

i suspect you have more columns in table and in program you are passing only two values now sql is consdiering that you have only two columns in your table to fix it you need to rewrite your sql query. i am using dummy column name please change it to your own columns.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        string strcmd = "INSERT INTO student (name, rollno) VALUES('" + txtsname.Text + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(txtsrollno.Text) + "')";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strcmd, MyConn);
        if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { MyConn.Open(); }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { MyConn.Close(); }

        showData();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } 
 }
```